# IPSET rules being ignored (CentOS 7)

Tags: linux, centos, firewall, firewalld, fail2ban

I've installed fail2ban on my CentOS 7 server. I've enabled the sshd jail which seems to be running correctly.

jail.local is running "banaction = firewallcmd-ipset"

For testing purposes, I repeatedly tried to connect to my server with an incorrect username. fail2ban correctly recognized and banned the offending IP, and then added the correct firewall rule.

However I am still able to ssh in via the banned IP.

Any ideas what's going on?

---

```
Status for the jail: sshd
|- Filter
|  |- Currently failed: 0
|  |- Total failed:     52
|  `- Journal matches:  _SYSTEMD_UNIT=sshd.service + _COMM=sshd
`- Actions
   |- Currently banned: 1
   |- Total banned:     2
   `- Banned IP list:   181.109.18.132
```

---

```
Name: fail2ban-sshd
Type: hash:ip
Revision: 1
Header: family inet hashsize 1024 maxelem 65536 timeout 3600
Size in memory: 16592
References: 1
Members:
181.109.18.132 timeout 2782
```

---

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  firewalld.service
● firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2016-08-04 17:21:01 ART; 24min ago
  Process: 9281 ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 8723 (firewalld)
   CGroup: /system.slice/firewalld.service
       └─8723 /usr/bin/python -Es /usr/sbin/firewalld --nofork --nopid
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I've switched to iptables and the problem persists.